# C# WinForms Move elements between panels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I need to create a form with two panels:
1. Destination
2. Source
On the source panel there will be picture boxes. I need to be able to move it from source to point at destination panel with mouse.

I have a problem connected with different coordinates of the panels.

Please, help with advice or an idea what to do.

Comment: The coordinates _of_ the panels should not matter... You get relative coords in your events.

Comment: This question is (too) broad. Better make a start and show where you get stuck.

Comment: Agree with Henk Holterman. Show us what you did already and then we will try to advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving those controls requires changing their Parent property.  That's not easy to do, there is no good time to do this while the user is dragging with the mouse.  You'll also get the effect of the panel clipping the control, you cannot display it on both with half of the control on one and the other half on the other panel.  And yes, you have to change the Location property of the control when you change the parent or it will jump.

Punt the problem, don't use two panels.  It only has to *look* like a panel, easily done by drawing one in the form's Paint method (or OnPaint override, better).  Use e.Graphics.DrawRectangle or FillRectangle.

Comment: ...or use the ControlPaint class for making it look more like a panel.